# Initialising Sequential values with for loop?

Tags: ceylon

Is there any way to initialize a Sequential value *not* in one fellow swoop?

Like, can I declare it, then use a for loop to populate it, step by step?

As this could all happen inside a class body, the true immutability of the Sequential value could then kick in once the class instance construction phase has been completed.

Example:

```
Sequential<String> strSeq;

for (i in span(0,10)) {
    strSeq[i] = "hello";
}
```

This code doesn't work, as I get this error:

> Error:(12, 9) ceylon: illegal receiving type for index expression:
>   'Sequential' is not a subtype of 'KeyedCorrespondenceMutator' or
>   'IndexedCorrespondenceMutator'

So what I can conclude is that sequences *must* be assigned in *one* statement, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets used to create a sequence literal accept not only a comma-separated list of values, but also a for-comprehension:

```
String[] strSeq = [for (i in 0..10) "hello"];
```

You can also do both at the same time, as long as the for-comprehension comes last:

```
String[] strSeq = ["hello", "hello", for (i in 0..8) "hello"];
```

In this specific case, you could also do this:

```
String[] strSeq = ["hello"].repeat(11);
```

You can also get a sequence of sequences via nesting:

```
String[][] strSeqSeq = [for (i in 0..2) [for (j in 0..2) "hello"]];
```

And you can do the cartesian product (notice that the nested for-comprehension here isn't in square brackets):

```
[Integer, Character][] pairs = [for (i in 0..2) for (j in "abc") [i, j]];
```

`Foo[]` is an abbreviation for `Sequential<Foo>`, and `x..y` translates to `span(x, y)`.

Comment: My actual use case involves a sequence of sequences! Can a for-loop comprehension also deal with that? i.e. can I put a for loop comprehension inside a for loop comprehension?

Comment: Absolutely! I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, several language guarantees hinge on the immutability of sequential objects, so that immutability must be guaranteed by the language – it can’t just trust you that you won’t mutate it after the initialization is done :)

Typically, what you do in this situation is construct some sort of collection (e. g. an `ArrayList` from `ceylon.collection`), mutate it however you want, and then take its `.sequence()` when you’re done.

Your specific case can also be written as a comprehension in a sequential literal:

```
String[] strSeq = [for (i in 0..10) "hello"];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know upfront the size of the sequence you want to create, then a very efficient way is to use an `Array`:

```
value array = Array.ofSize(11, "");
for (i in 0:11) {
    array[i] = "hello";
}
String[] strSeq = array.sequence();
```

On the other hand, if you *don't* know the size upfront, then, as described by Lucas, you need to use either:

- a comprehension, or
- some sort of growable array, like `ArrayList`.

Comment: this is what I ended up doing.